# Why use static if in D?

Tags: templates, d

I have been reading about the template system in the D language and came upon a unusual construct, `static if`.

From what I managed to grasp it is evaluated at compile time, but from what I have searched, the example shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_programming_language) did not quite enlighten me.

```
template Factorial(ulong n)
{
    static if(n < 2)
        const Factorial = 1;
    else
        const Factorial = n * Factorial!(n - 1);
}
```

What does `static if` do, and when should I use it?

Comment: didn't get what actually you are expecting , Please elaborate the problem

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes From what I know this is intended as a superseed of C++

Comment: @aravind.udayashankara I do not really understand what the static if does.

Comment: @coredump if you mean "superset", then no. D is nowhere near a superset of C++.

Comment: @coredump: not exactly. D is NOT a superseed of C++. Both C++ and D are differnet superseed of C (in the sense that can link C functions and support the same expression model) with different backward compatibility respect to C

Comment: It is debatable. I would actually agree to some extend. Name one C++ language feature that D does not have. I can, on the other hand, list few D features that C++ does not have (and probably will never have).

Comment: Whereas if @coredump means "[supersede](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/supersede)", then we can all only dream of the day...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the D `static if` is the base for "conditional compilation", and plays an important role wherever a compile time decision about a variant of a code must be taken.

Since D doesn't have a preprocessor, things like

```
#ifdef xxx
compile_this_piece_of_code
#endif
```

can become

```
static if(xxx)
{
     compile_this_pece_of_code
}
```

similarly, metaprogramming can happen also via static if:

```
template<int x>
struct traits
{ some definition calculated from x };

template<>
struct traits<0>
{ same definitions for the 0 particular case }
```

can be

```
template(int x)
{
    static if(x==0)
    { some definitions }
    else
    { some other same definitions }
    even more definition common in the two cases
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think what confused me was the function like usage .

Comment: Btw. First example will not compile. For that D has the `version(XXX) {} else {}`

Comment: It depends on what xxx actually is: if it is a symbol, version is the statement, if it is a constant expression static_if works.  The right example is most likely not `#ifdef...` but `#if ....`

Comment: So why don't you change it in your answer?

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia example is actually pretty simple:

```
template Factorial(ulong n)
{
    static if(n < 2)
        const Factorial = 1;
    else
        const Factorial = n * Factorial!(n - 1);
}
```

It is an eponymous template (See Jonathan's comment below). `n` is the template parameter. So, what if you instead wrote:

```
template Factorial(ulong n)
{
    if(n < 2) // NOTE: no static here
        const Factorial = 1;
    else
        const Factorial = n * Factorial!(n - 1);
}
```

? - It will not work. Check http://dpaste.dzfl.pl/3fe074f2 . The reason is the fact that static if and "normal" if have different semantics. `static if` takes an assignment expression ( http://dlang.org/version.html , section "Static If") that is evaluated at *compile time*, while normal if takes an expression that is evaluated at run-time.

`Static if` is just one way to do the "conditional compilation" mentioned by Emilio. D also has the `version` keyword. So Emilio's first conditional compilation example (which does not work in D) becomes something like:

```
version (XXX) { 
    // XXX defined 
} else { 
    // XXX not defined 
}
```

If you want to use static if for this, you would write something like:

```
enum int XXX = 10;
static if (XXX == 10) {
    pragma(msg, "ten");
}
```

Comment: Factorial's not a template function. It's an eponymous template. Uses of the template are replaced with the result of the template which is the symbol inside the template with the same name as the template - e.g. `Factorial!5` becomes `120`. It's entirely a compile time construct. This is completely different from a templated function which is called like any other function but is instantiated with differently depending on the types of its arguments. Based on your answer, I'm guessing that you understand it and just have the terminology wrong, but you're going to cause confusion as it is.

Comment: Correct. :) I am going to update my answer so the terminology is right.

Answer (score 3):

Andrei Alexandrescu has a good talk that you can watch here about static if in a C++ context (if that's what your asking for).

Link: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Static-If-I-Had-a-Hammer

Short answer- it makes the syntax for some template metaprogramming a lot more intuitive.

Comment: Walter also touched `static if` in one of his presentations, I just forgot which one... :)

Answer (score 1):

Andrei Alexandrescu has lately been calling smart use of `static if` "Design by Introspection", with some great examples ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=es6U7WAlKpQ), [slides](http://dconf.org/2017/talks/alexandrescu.pdf)).

A direct example from his talk would be implementing a generic container such as a hash table using Robin Hood hashing, where an extra data (probe count) is kept with each entry in the table. With `static if` we can optimize memory automatically by placing the probe count next to the key based on its alignment, optimize integer width for the index type, etc.

Paraphrased from the talk:

```
struct RobinHashTable(K, V, size_t maxLength) {
  static if (maxLength < ushort.max-1) {
    alias CellIdx = ushort;
  } else {
    alias CellIdx = uint;
  }

  static if (K.sizeof % 8 < 7) {
    align(8) struct KV {
      align(1):
        K k;
        ubyte cellData;
      align(8):
        V v;
    }
  } else {
    align(8) struct KV {
      align(8):
        K k;
        V v;
      align(1):
        ubyte cellData;
    }
  }
}
```